# Appending data in form request laravel inside array

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form request which I need to validate . If I dd the $request->all() it shows me the following result.

```
"adults_information" => array:1 [▼
 0 => array:6 [▼
  "first_name" => "Luke"
  "last_name" => "Greer"
  "dob_day" => "08"
  "dob_month" => "01"
  "dob_year" => 1935
  "gender" => "M"
]]
"contact_name" => "Eula Dennis"
"mobile_number" => "7308001726"
```

What I want is to create extra field after dob_year such as dob which constist of calculation of dob_day,"dob_year","dob_month" . I want some line of code such that when I do dd($request->all()) . I want to get the output like this .

```
"adults_information" => array:1 [▼
 0 => array:6 [▼
  "first_name" => "Luke"
  "last_name" => "Greer"
  "dob_day" => "08"
  "dob_month" => "01"
  "dob_year" => 1935
  "gender" => "M",
  "dob"=>"1935-01-08"
]]
"contact_name" => "Eula Dennis"
"mobile_number" => "7308001726"
```

I tried $request->add() but it didn't work . Any help will be appriciated

Comment: `$request->adults_information[0][] = '';`

Comment: Because it is $request->request->add();

Comment: I think that you need `php array_push`

Answer (score 3):

The correct syntax is not $request->add but $request->request->add.

So:

```
$request->request->add([
    'adults_information'=>$request->adults_information + ['dob' => '1935-01-08']
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    $inputs = $request->all();
    foreach($inputs['adults_information'] as $key => $info)
    {
        $dob = $info['dob_year'].'-'.
               $info['dob_month'].'-'.
               $info['dob_day'];

        $inputs['adults_information'][$key]['dob'] = $dob;
    }
    $request->merge($inputs);
    dd($request->all());
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi u can use `merge()` with array_push to push a nested array.

```
$adults_information = $request->adults_information;
    $insert = [
        "first_name" => "Luke",
        "last_name" => "Greer",
        "dob_day" => "08",
        "dob_month" => "01",
        "dob_year" => 1935,
        "gender" => "M",
        "dob"=>"1935-01-08"
    ];
    array_push($adults_information, $insert);

    $request->merge('adults_information', $adults_information);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can use replace method for appending item to request object. For more details you can check Laravel API docs https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_replace . For example.

```
$data = $request->all();
$data['appending_data_1'] = 'dummy value';
$data['appending_data_2'] = 'dummy value';
$request->replace($data);
```